# Turn On Notification Programatically in My Android app

Tags: java, android, service, notifications, accessibility

I want to turn On **notification** Access for my android app programitically.

In some android devices, Notification Access for my app is turned off by default. I want to turn **On** and turn **Off** the notification access for my app dynamically in the app itself.

But I don't have any idea on how to enable the service.

Please, provide me your views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible. There are restrictions for android applications which you can pass only with root.

Answer (score 0):

Use that kind of metod on your Activity

```
 public void sendNotification() {

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.journaldev.com/"));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    builder.setContentTitle("Notification title");
    builder.setContentText("Your notification message.");
    builder.setSubText("link for more info.");

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
}

public void cancelNotification() {

    String ns = NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ns);
    nMgr.cancel(1);
}
```

Comment: I dont want to send push notification. i want to enable the Notification for my app through code. like here   https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz6Df.png

Answer (score 0):

You can prompt user to set those permissions for proper functioning. Setting those within app sounds malicious. I highly doubt such thing is possible. *(Why would google create permission in first place if they can be overridden by app?)*